# How to show a particular month and year in FSCalender?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

With regards to my previous question, I have one more problem that I am facing. In a view controller I have a collection view and FSCalender. In the collectionview, there is a list of months which I am getting from API and with respect to that month there is a year too.

Something Like this:

[image]

On clicking the month, we get the respective year on the left label.

Now, my question is how can I get the particular month which I click and its respective year on the Calender.
I have tried this so far to get the month.

```
let index = indexPath.item + 10
let currentMonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: calender.currentPage)
let month = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: index - currentMonth, to: calender.currentPage)
calender.setCurrentPage(month!, animated: true)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have the month and year values, you can change any date components on the calendar like this:

```swift
let month = 3 // March
let year = 2022
var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: calender.currentPage)
dateComponents.setValue(month, for: .month)
dateComponents.setValue(year, for: .year)
let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
calender.setCurrentPage(date!, animated: true)
```

And similar for any other date component if you need - `.day`, `.hour`, `.minute`, `.second`, etc.

Comment: It only gives me the current month and year. What if I want the calender for march, 2022

Comment: I updated the answer for more clarity. You can change to any values you want. I'm not sure how is the relation between month/year on the collection view you have, maybe you could detail that more? Is March on the 3rd item of a section, is a year corresponding to the section number?

Comment: See, I am getting the data in the collectionview from API. The data contains some particular months of some particular year(like march 2022, Jan 2020, dec 2021). The data is going to change in future so I can't give some static value. I want a logic which checks which month and year is clicked and then show that specific month with year in calender.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But we can't give you a complete answer without knowing more how you implemented the rest. You need a way to access the values you display on the collection view cell/section, then you can use them to change the calendar. Could you add these details to your question? How do you populate the cells / sections of your collection view? What's the model you use on your data source?

Comment: I got the way to access the values for both month and year. Thanks!

Comment: @LetUsDevelop Glad to hear that! I'd appreciate if you marked my answer as accepted.